# How to force WinInet and MSXML to use TLS1.0

Tags: msxml, wininet

We are using WinInet and MSXML in our application. Is there any way to force these libraries to use TLS1.0 to fix the poodle vulnerability?

Comment: I couldn't find any option to set in WinInet or MSXML.

Answer (score 0):

Wininet uses schannel.dll for the SSL/TLS communication and will automatically negotiate TLS if the server side offers TLS.  There is nothing for you to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you application is running on a server, you can disable SSL 3.0 for the entire server.  Here are the steps per a [Microsoft Security Advisory](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/security/3009008.aspx#ID0EMG).

1. Click Start, click Run, type regedt32 or type regedit, and then click OK.
2. In Registry Editor, locate the following registry key: HKey_Local_Machine\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\SSL 3.0\Server
   Note If the complete registry key path does not exist, you can create it by expanding the available keys and using the New -> Key option from the Edit menu.
3. On the Edit menu, click Add Value.
4. In the Data Type list, click DWORD.
5. In the Value Name box, type Enabled, and then click OK. 
   Note If this value is present, double-click the value to edit its current value.
   In the Edit DWORD (32-bit) Value dialog box, type 0 .
6. Click OK. Restart the computer.

Client side is pretty much the same steps, but change the registry key path from ..\SSL 3.0\Server to ..\SSL 3.0\Client